# Time related token return "0"

Tags: rules, bookings

Am using the [Booking time slots](https://www.drupal.org/project/booking_timeslots) module. The rules tokens that are related to calendar/time return "0"
Examples of the token include: [booking:slot-time], [booking:hour-start] and[booking:min-start]

Please does anyone know a variation, I can use?